# Concatenating objects of different types into a string (Python)

Tags: python, string

I have been learning Python for two weeks now
I created a function which displays your biographical data.
I want to know how to put objects of different data types into one string

As you can see, the data includes strings, an int and a boolean.
I want to be able to display them as a single string. So far my function only displays them individually like this: ('1000000', 'Bob', 17, False)
I want to it display like this: '<1000000,Bob,17,False>'

```
def student_data(name, age, student_number, enrolled):
    age = int(age)
    true = "true"
    false = "false"
    # check to see if user is enrolled or not.
    if enrolled == true:        
        enrolled = True
    else:        
        enrolled = False
    data = (student_number, name, age, enrolled,) 
    return (data)

data = student_data("Jana", 17, "1001291657", "false")
print (data)
```

Comment: Please do not define 'true' and 'false' the way you have. *VERY* unpythonic. Just use the builtins `True` and `False`. Otherwise people will look at you funny...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you just want to show them ,simply use a function like this:

```
def student_data(name, age, student_number, enrolled):
 print "name:{0}, age:{1}, student_number:{2}, enrolled :{3}".fromat(name, age, student_number, enrolled)
```

and if you want to convert all of them to one string use this :

```
def student_data(name, age, student_number, enrolled):
   my_str=str(name)+','+str(age)+','+str(student_number)+','+str(enrolled)
   return my_str
```

as an alternative answer its better to pass your arguments in a list to function and use `map` and `join` built in functions for create a **pythonic** code for this aim :

```
my_list = [name, age, student_number, enrolled]
    def student_data(my_list):
     return ','.join(map(str,mylist))
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! The second method you showed was very easy to understand (Y)

Comment: thanks ... there are many suggestion for a question like this as you see in answers but i answer base on your request ! so i will add another ways in edit to answer !

Answer (score 4):

The easy answer to the question 'Concatenating objects of different types into a string' is to use map:

```
>>> list_of_obj=['string', 1234, 123.4, {1:'one'}]
>>> map(str, list_of_obj)
['string', '1234', '123.4', "{1: 'one'}"]
```

Or a list comprehension:

```
>>> [str(e) for e in list_of_obj]
['string', '1234', '123.4', "{1: 'one'}"]
```

In each case, you are applying the built-in function [str](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) to each object in a list.

However, may I suggest writing a class to keep track of students:

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age, number, enrolled=True):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.number=number
        self.enrolled=enrolled
```

Then add a method to the class to format it the way you want:

```
    # Note indentation to be part of the class definition of Student...
    def __str__(self):
        seq=(self.name, self.age, self.number, self.enrolled)
        return '<{}>'.format(', '.join([str(e) for e in seq]))
```

Then create a student:

```
>>> student1=Student('Bob Jones', 23, 12345, True)
```

Then the format is as you define it to be:

```
>>> print student1   
<Bob Jone, 23, 12345, True>
```

As stated in the comments, I find it not so Pythonic to redefine `true = "true"` and `false = "false"` Just use `True` and `False` directly. The main reason, besides not confusing others (or yourself) is that you loose Python's sense of 'truthy' vs 'falsey':

```
>>> false = "false"
>>> bool(false)
True
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a list of strings by converting your objects like this

```
[str(i) for i in data]
```

Then it's just a matter of joining the list together with join() method.
Last lines of your code would look like this:

```
data = student_data("Jana", 17, "1001291657", "false")
string_data = ",".join([str(i) for i in data])
print("<{}>".format(string_data)) # adding brackets with format()
```